# CountIfs function giving incorrect result

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to count the number of items in a list between two dates.

The two dates will move each week, therefore within the `countifs` function it refers to a cell rather than hard coding the date - it does not recognize the lookup date (**puts " " around it**) even if I convert the date to *numeric* format.

If i do the same but hardcode the date it works.

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please add some sample data with desired results to help us understanding your issue. (take a screenshot, upload it to e.g. [imgur](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), then post the link in your question; or you can format your data as a table [here](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using COUNTIFS, consider setting up two formulas in adjacent columns.

```
Cell B5:  =IF(AND(A5>=$C$1,A5<=$C$2),1,0)
Cell C5:  =SUM(B$5:B5)
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Then hide column B.